# Is it possible for my app to detect if my device has barcode scanner? (For example Zebra)

Tags: android, hardware, software-design

I would like to ask, if it's possible for any app to detect if device has barcode scanner connected? Like Zebra TC26. I want my app to work diffrent when there is hardware connected scanner and when there isn't any.

Comment: How did you do it finally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DataWedge API - Enumerate Scanners](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-2/guide/api/enumeratescanners/) which generates an index of scanners available on the device. You can check that and change the app behaviur based on the results.

[Here's the complete list](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-2/guide/api/) of avaliable DataWedge API's. And just in case you haven't worked with this, here's the [main guide](https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/8-2/guide/programmers-guides/).

Comment: DataWedge is only applicable for zebra devices i guess ? what about if it's connected to any other OEM scanners